# Create class instances from data

Tags: php

I've got a PHP class, and I'd like to create instances I can update later from the data that I pull from the database. Here's what I've got so far:

```
<?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "super";
    $password = "cala";
    $database = "fraga";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $getTableQuery = "SELECT ani.Id, ani.Name, ani.Size, ani.Color, tbs.Name as Species, tbs.Description
    FROM animals as ani INNER JOIN 
         animalTypes as tbs ON ani.Species = tbs.Id
    ORDER BY ani.Id";

    $table = $conn->query($getTableQuery);
    $pageLoaded = false;

    if(isset($_POST['btnInsert']) && ($_POST['txtName'] != "")){
        $pageLoaded = true;
    }

    if ($table->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>Name</th><th>Size</th><th>Color</th><th>Species</th></tr>";
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $table->fetch_assoc()) {   
            echo "<tr><td>".$row["Name"]."</td><td>".$row["Size"]."</td><td>".$row["Color"]."</td><td>".$row["Species"]."</td></tr>";
            $fish[] = $row;
        }
        echo "</table>";
        echo "</br>";

    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['btnInsert']) && ($_POST['btnInsert'] == "Insert") && $pageLoaded == true)
    {
        $Animal = new Animal($_POST['txtName'], $_POST['txtSize'], $_POST['txtColor'], $_POST['txtSpecies'], $_POST['txtDescription']);

        $Animal->InsertAnimal($conn);
    }else if(isset($_POST['btnSave']) && ($_POST['btnSave'] == "Save") && $pageLoaded == true){
        $Animal->UpdateAnimal($Animal);
    }

    class Animal
    {
        private $name = "Animal Name";
        private $size = 0;
        private $color = "255:255:255";
        private $speciesName = "Species Name";
        private $speciesDescription = "Species Description";

        public function Animal($name, $size, $color, $species, $description){
            $this->name = $name;
            $this->size = $size;
            $this->color = $color;
            $this->speciesName = $species;
            $this->speciesDescription = $description;
        }

        private function ColorCheck($color){
            if($color >= 256 || $color <= 0)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }

        public function InsertAnimal($conn, $pageLoaded){
            $this->speciesName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $this->speciesName);
            $this->speciesDescription = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $this->speciesName);
            $this->name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $this->name);
            $this->size = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $this->size);
            $this->color = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $this->color);


            $speciesId = "SELECT Id from animalTypes WHERE Name = '$this->speciesDescription'";
            $speciesInsert = "INSERT IGNORE INTO animalTypes (Name, Description) 
                                            VALUES ('$this->speciesName', '$this->speciesDescription')";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $speciesInsert) or die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error($conn));

            if($id = $conn->query($speciesId)){
                $row = $id->fetch_assoc();
                $intId = $row['Id'];
            }

            $AnimalInsert = "INSERT INTO animals (Name, Size, Color, Species)
                                 VALUES ('$this->name', $this->size, '$this->color', $intId)";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $AnimalInsert) or die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error($conn));

            echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = window.location.href;</script>';

            $_POST['txtName'] = "";
        }

        public function UpdateAnimal($animal, $conn){
            $speciesCheck = "SELECT * FROM animalTypes WHERE Name = '$this->speciesName";
            $speciesList = mysqli_query($conn, $speciesCheck) or die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error($conn));


            $updateQuery = "UPDATE animals";
        }
    }
    $conn->close();
?>

<body>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
    Animal Name:<br />
    <input name="txtName" type="text" /><br />
    <br />
    Size:<br />
    <input name="txtSize" type="text" /><br />
    <br />
    Color:<br />
    <input name="txtColor" type="text" /><br />
    <br />
    Species Name:<br />
    <input name="txtSpecies" type="text" /><br />
    <br />
    Species Description:<br />
    <input name="txtDescription" style="width: 419px; height: 125px" type="text" /><br />
    <br />
    <input name="btnInsert" type="submit" value="Insert" />
    <input name="btnSave" type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>

</body>
```

Now, what I'd like to do is create instances of `Animal` from the data that loads when the page loads, and store them for update. Problem is, I'm not sure how to do it. I've googled a bit (but my fu is admittedly weak), and saw suggestion for creating an array of `Animals` and adding them during the `while` loop. Is that really the best way to do that? And then how could I load the instance back into the text boxes so that I could update them?

Comment: PHP4 constructors? ;-)

Comment: If you're using PHP5.x you should name your constructor __construct().
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php
And name your functions and variables in lower case letters.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should learn to seperate the concerns in your code correctly.
If I started to explain how you should build your script up from scratch, this would take too long, so I will try to give you only a good direction to go. I think this will help you more in your learning process.

So, if I understand correctly, the code you posted is all set up in one file, I guess it's inside you index.php? (missing some information here)

If this is the case...

### index.php

Use your index.php for displaying a list of your "Animals" from db, not more. Every list entry will have an *edit* and *delete* button/link next to it. On top of your list put a link that's called *create*.

Now all your index.php does is getting the animals from db and listing them.

Put this part of your code in another file, called dbconfig.php

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "super";
$password = "cala";
$database = "fraga";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

include it on top of your index.php, before you start scripting the index.php

```
include 'dbconfig.php'
```

now you can use your $conn variable inside you index.php. We put this into another file and included it, because we're going to reuse this part in the next steps.

I won't write your whole code here for index.php, I think you'll master that. Maybe you ask yourself what your *create*, *edit*, *delete* links should do.

- The *create* link point to a create.php, a simple html link.
- The *edit* link, you will have to render an html link to edit.php?id=IDOfYourAnimalInsideDB
- The *delete* link looks like the edit one, put a link to delete.php?id=IDOfYourAnimalInsideDB.

So where I wrote "IDOfYourAnimalInsideDB" you have to output the actual id, this will be done in your while loop.

### create.php

first of all, include the dbconfig.php again here, so you can use your $conn variable which has the db connection.

check if the request has some of your post variables, if true, build an instance of animal and write it to db.

outside the *if* you build your form. So it doesn't matter if it's post or not, you will show the create form.

### delete.php

Again the dbconfig.php include first.
Then you want to check if $_GET['id'] is set and maybe if it's bigger than 0 and if its an integer value. If so, execute your delete sql to the db.

### update.php

Again the dbconfig.php include first.
Then you want to check your GET Parameter again and build an sql request to get your specific database entry. 
Output a form that already contains your values from db. If a post request comes, you create a new Animal instance, fill it with your data from $_POST and then use it for updating your db.

### getters in Animal Class

add getter functions to you animal class, so you can access the private properties from outside. you should write you create, update, delete logic inside the create.php, update.php, delete.php or in another class which you use for database manipulation. There you want to get access to properties for example in order to build up your update sql.
So make a getter method for every property of your "Animal" model class

```
public function getName() {
    return $this->name;
}
```

so from outside you can get your animals name like so

```
$animalName = $animal->getName();
```

### more specific?

If you need something more specific, you should specify a little bit more your question. What I described is just a way that splits your script into parts you can understand and maintain better, because stucture and correct seperation of things is one of the most important things in programming.
What I described is far far away from a clean "CRUD" solution, but I think this is a little step for you that you can take now to come closer to a clean solution.

Kind regards

Comment: Just forgot about the animal class ... if you want to reuse it over all php files, just output it to animal.php and include it on top of all your files, like we did for dbconfig.php.